# Retrofit ArrayList gets send as object if it holds one element

Tags: java, gson, retrofit

When using retrofit I have the problem that when I have this List:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("item1");
```

and I put this in retrofit with the gson converter then I get this as output:

```
{ "item1" }
```

While when I have this:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("item1");
items.add("item2");
```

then I get

```
[ "item1", "item2" ]
```

Is there anything I can do about this? I tried writing a custom provider like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new List1ElementAsArrayAdapter());
```

With List1ElementAsArrayAdapter being this:

```
public class List1ElementAsArrayAdapter implements JsonSerializer<List<?>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<?> list, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        if (list.size() == 1) {
            // Don't put single element lists in a json array
            return new Gson().toJsonTree(list.get(0));
        } else {
            return new Gson().toJsonTree(list);
        }
    }
}
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a good solution for this so I decided to change what I was doing.

Instead of just creating a List of the type String I am now creating a JSONArray object and adding all my keys to that one.

Example:

```
JSONArray ids = new JSONArray();
ids.put("item1");
```

this correctly gives back what I wanted. Hopefully this helps other people that are having the same issue as me.